# Reconstructing data and then Plotting it

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having difficulty reconstructing the data and the transforming it back using the function inverse_transform. I am trying to create a plot that contains 5 figures with different principal components highlighted in the array: some_arr. I also want to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors to reconstruct the data. Could you help me with that as well as plotting the figures? The code also says there is invalid syntax with

X = scaler.fit(ReconX)_transform(ReconX):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have attached my code below:

```
some_arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
df_s = StandardScaler().fit_transform(C) #Standardize C 
df_cov = np.dot(df_std.T, df_std) / (n-1)

for i in range(0, len(some_arr)):
   P=eigenVectors[:, 0:i]
   W = eigenVectors[:, 0:some_arr]
   projX = np.dot(X_std, W) #finds the projection
   X_std.shape, W.shape , projX.shape
   ReconX = np.dot(projX, W.T)
   
   X = scaler.fit(ReconX)_transform(ReconX):
   Inv = scaler.inverse_transform(X)
   X = scaler.inverse_transform() #inverse transform use your FITTED scaler
```

Comment: You've got 2 separate questions, reconstructing and plotting. As to the syntax error likely you should have X = scaler.fit_transform(ReconX)

Comment: Do you think the procedure for reconstruction of the data is good?